# Selecting from db using a date range - Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object

Tags: php, sql, date

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
.........
```

The variables are passing correctly and I have checked my database credentials and they are all correct but I am still getting the error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

$dbh->query  probably returns null if nothing is found in the database.

so only loop through the results if there actually are results

```
if($stmt){
  while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  ...
```